# What's な doing in 絶えなんとする?

Tags: grammar, verbs, classical-japanese

I'm reading Harry Potter in Japanese and it goes:

> 力は失せ、命も絶えなんとする姿で、ヴォルデモートは逃げ去った。
> His powers gone, his life almost
> extinguished, Voldemort had fled;

命も絶えんとする姿で would make sense to me, but it's a bit confusing with the extra な. What is it? Can it be the perfective ぬ (as in 風が立ちぬ =The wind has risen)?

Comment: Why they used an expression like this in a children’s book is beyond me.

Comment: 読んだことないですが、ファンタジー作品ならこういう古めかしい表現もあるのかなー、と思ってました。現代文では「さもありなん」を除けばまず見ないですよね…。

Comment: @aguijonazo I have often heard people say that the translation of Harry Potter is strange, but I don't think I've ever found a breakdown of why people think so.

Comment: @Leebo By googling "harry potter 翻訳おかしい," you can find some interesting Japanese threads like https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13174025388

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that な is the irrealis form (未然形) of ぬ from classical Japanese. ぬ is usually the auxiliary for the perfective aspect (as in 風立ちぬ), but when it's combined with an auxiliary of inference such as [ん (=む)](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009010.htm), it emphatically adds the degree of certainty.

> ##### [ぬ](https://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009005.htm)
>
> (2) **強意**…［きっと～・～してしまう］
>
> 船にのり**なん**とす。（土佐日記・一二月二七日）
> 　（船に乗ってしまおうとする。）
>
> ※「つ」・「ぬ」＋推量の助動詞
> 　つべし・ぬべし・てむ・にむ・つらむ・ぬらむ・てまし・なまし・にけむ・てけむ
> 　などの**推量の助動詞とともに用いられる場合は強意**となる。

> ##### [ぬ](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AC)
>
> ②〔確述〕きっと…だろう。間違いなく…はずだ。▽多く、**「む」**「らむ」「べし」など**推量の意を表す語とともに用いられて**、その事態が確実に起こることを予想し強調する。

> ##### [完了の助動詞「つ」「ぬ」を解説！【古典文法】](https://blaao.net/2020/06/19/kanryou-tsu-nu/)
>
> ###### 推量（系）の助動詞と連携
>
> この「つ」「ぬ」は推量（系）の助動詞（いずれ出てきます）とも連携します。そして、なんと推量と連携する時、「つ」「ぬ」は新たな文法的意味を獲得します。それが **「強意」**。
>
> この時の「つ」や「ぬ」の意味は「完了」ではなくて「強意」です。**訳す際には、「きっと〜だろう」と訳し**、「きっと」のところに「強意」の意味が反映されています。

So:

- 絶えん (絶えむ) = 絶えるだろう
- 絶え**な**ん (絶えなむ) = **間違いなく**絶えるだろう/絶えて**しまう**だろう

See [this entry](https://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%80), too.

Comment: Fascinating question and answer. I have a question about native speakers' general knowledge of this type of construction. Do native Japanese speakers only understand such things because they have studied 文語 at school? Or do they have a kind of vague intuition about some Classical constructions (e.g. -む ~= だろう) even though they have never formally studied Classical Japanese?

Comment: @jogloran Simple ん/む for volition/inference (e.g., いざ行かん, さもあらん) is relatively common in manga and lyrics, so most people know how it works intuitively. なん/なむ is much less common, and average native speakers don't understand it intuitively. I think I knew about it before the university entrance exam, but I had forgotten about it until yesterday.